# If checkbox in a form is ticked add it to the resulting div class

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, checkbox, echo

I am using a Wordpress plugin called Multi Rating Pro. When a user submits a rating on the page the result appears in a separate div on the same page.

I want to (as simply as possible) insert my own checkbox into the rating form and if its ticked, output a value in the resulting div class.

For example, inside the rating form I would add something like -

```
<input type="checkbox" name="anon" value="yes"> Rate anonymously
```

Then in the resulting div I would be looking for the class of 'yes' to be added to the div if the checkbox was checked on submission, like -

```
<div class="rating-result yes"></div>
```

How would I go about doing this? I assume the way in which he form is submitted would play a part but am unsure of its workings...

Comment: checkout my answer. I made the code a lost easier without ajax.

Comment: click this link for test https://jsfiddle.net/5su8wjap/4/

Comment: Is this the only checkbox that you have, or is it a list  of checkboxes?  In other words, do you just need the result of the checkbox to record a value and have the div show up after submitting?

Comment: Its a full on form with dynamic fields and ratings, its an existing plugin. The div already shows up. I just need know how I can add this one field and output the value in the resulting div

Answer (score 0):

First provide an Id to your input, in my case i used anon. [Click here for example](https://jsfiddle.net/5su8wjap/4/)

```
 <input type="checkbox" value="Yes" id="anon"><br/>
  <div class="rating-result"></div>

$('#anon').click(function(){
    var value = $('#anon').val();
    $('.rating-result').html('Your Rating:' +' '+ value);
})
```

Comment: Thanks for this Sam, unfortunately this is not what I'm after. I need the value to submit with the form and be stored so when the page is refreshed the results still have the class applied.